# How can I rediredct the URL formed in WEb API to a web site in a different domain

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Below is a Web API(Rest WebService which is interacting with Android phone) method for Forgot Password Functionality.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("ForgotPassword")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
        //if (user == null ||!(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
        if (user == null)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        var code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
        var callbackUrl = Url.Link("Default", new { Controller = "Account", Action = "ResetPassword", code = code });
        /*await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password",
           "Please reset your password by clicking here : <a href=\""+ callbackUrl +"\">link</a>"); */
        await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password",$"{callbackUrl}");
        return Ok();
    }
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

The CallbackURL formed is

```
http://localhost:[port number]/Account/ResetPassword?code=[code value] ...
```

But instead of localhost address, I want it to point to another domain(server) address. 
Is there a possibility that I can generate my required URL using the URL.Link method?

Comment: Hi ekad.. Can u guide me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You could respond with a status 301 which you can create with the HttpStatusCode.Moved. The 301 will generate a get request to the URI specified in the location header. 
You could read more about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("ForgotPassword")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
        //if (user == null ||!(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
        if (user == null)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        var code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
        var callbackUrl = Url.Link("Default", new { Controller = "Account", Action = "ResetPassword", code = code });
        /*await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password",
           "Please reset your password by clicking here : <a href=\""+ callbackUrl +"\">link</a>"); */
        await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password",$"{callbackUrl}");

        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Moved);
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri("http://www.yourNewDomain.com");
        return response;
    }

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```